# Appending HTML content via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a page where I load comments on demand by using jQuery. I have `<div id="comments">` where I append HTML by formatting a predefined template.

My template is as follows : 
`<div class="entry clearfix" style="position: absolute; left: 1oopx; top: 20px;">
    <div class="comment-image">
        <img class="image_fade" src="<#ImageUri#>" alt="<#Header#>">
    </div>
    <div class="entry-title">
        <h2><a href="/Blog/Coments/<#Uri#>"><#Header#></a></h2>
    </div>
    <ul class="entry-meta clearfix">
        <li><i class="icon-calendar3"></i>  <#CommentDate#></li>
        <li><i class="icon-user">  <#Handle#></i></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="entry-content">
       <#Body#>
    </div>
</div>`;

I use a jQuery GET to get comment content then I replace the content as follows :

`html += blogitemHtml
            .replace(/<#ImageUri#>/g, item.ImageUri)
            .replace(/<#Header#>/g, item.Header)
            .replace(/<#Uri#>/g, item.FriendlyUri)
            .replace(/<#CommenDate#>/g, item.PublishedOn)
            .replace(/<#Handle#>/g, item.Handle)
            .replace(/<#Body#>/g, item.Intro);`

`$("#comments").append(html);`

The problem is data in Body is also and HTML document with tags. So instead of a formatted text I see HTML tags instead.

I know I could use the jQuery html() function but it changes the content of the div, where I want to append new content.

How can I possibly add the content and displayed it in a formatted way as the HTML tags should.

Example I should see:

This is my **first** comment. And I would like to thank you with this [video](https://youtube.com)

Bu instead I see : 
`<p> This is my <b>first</b> comment. And I would like to thank you with this <a href="https://youtube.com">video</a>.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`parseHTML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to parse the string into into an array of DOM nodes.

```
var htmlNodes = $.parseHTML( html);
$("#comments").append(htmlNodes );
```